# PhpStorm, about ftp sync

Tags: php, phpstorm

Just trying out this IDE but it already looks better than NetBeans in terms of speed and usability.. However, the main reason I chose it was the ftp sync feature, which.. doesn't seem to be working? When I create new project from existing files -> from remote server, ftp, it downloads the files and that's it. If I open it with open directory it doesn't upload changes to the server. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please refer to the [corresponding help section](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/uploading-and-downloading-files.html). For the synchronization feature see [Comparing Deployed Files and Folders with Their Local Versions](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html).

`File` | `Synchronize` is not related to remote hosts at all, it synchronizes the files with the file system in case external changes were not detected automatically for some reason or you've disabled automatic files synchronization on frame activation.

Answer (score 32):

With your project loaded, go to settings by either going to File > Settings or by pressing 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

From here go to Deployment > Options and then tick the "Uploaded changed files automatically to the default server".

It's also worth ticking the "Upload external changes" setting below; this will keep your local copy and the ftp copy synchronized by removing/renaming etc any file changes you make.

Comment: How do I load the project? Should I just "Open a directory"?

Comment: Yes; either that or just to to File > Open Recent if it's a recently opened project.

Comment: No, still nothing :(
If I press on a project and select "Synchronize 'xxx'", it just immediately says
"Synchronize 'xxx' completed successfully" and that's all.

Comment: Well, I did this settings and it didn't work. I had to click on Tools -> Deplayment -> Automatic Uploads (always) to get it run :)

Comment: This is worth noting this only works if you are using the default key scheme, and not something like the netbeans  version :-)

Answer (score 2):

when you are going to the real way to sync your file with the remote ftp/sftp server. You should use the "Tools/Deployment/Uploads to xxxxx".

i think this will do help to u.

Answer (score 1):

After ticking "Uploaded changed files automatically to the default server"
and setting up FTP server and its mapping, click on the button "Use this server as default" in the mapping tab.

Answer (score 0):

With Automatic Uploads checked ON, it is uploads files automatically even before I'm done making changes to the PHP files and resulting in INCOMPLETE script files. It is also uploading files in other tab pages. Looks like there is no precise control on uploads in PhpStorm